# Why does my script return a TypeError when comparing getA1Notation to a string?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I am trying to write a custom script that is bound to my Google spreadsheet. I want to trigger it using `onEdit(e)` based on the value changing in the dropdown located in `B3` of `'Pax Split Sheet'`.

I had it working in a limited way, but it was causing problems because the custom function was running whenever  `B3` was edited in *any* sheet, not just `'Pax Split Sheet'!B3`.

I switched the `onEdit` to a normal function for testing and also added a couple of `if` statements to first check that both the sheet name and the active cell are correct,  but I'm now getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: activeSheet.getRange.getA1Notation is not a function
```

Here is a sample of the code up to where it errors:

```
function hltcells(){

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetNameTest = activeSheet.getSheetName();

  if (activeSheet.getSheetName() == 'Pax Split Sheet'){
    
    if (activeSheet.getRange.getA1Notation() === 'B3'){
```

Comment: I eventually figured this one out by using the layout from this YouTube channel > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0p4PexixhA

Answer (score 0):

### onEdit(e): Sheet Name & Range

Simple `onEdit(e)` trigger that verifies the edited range and the sheet name

```
function onEdit(e) {
   
  if ((e.range.getA1Notation() == "B3") &&
      (e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Sheet1")){
      
    Logger.log("Action Performed!");
  
  }

}
```

Resources:

- [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation)
- [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetname)
- [Simple Triggers - includes `onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Equivalent script that first stores values in variables

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const matchCell="B3";
  const matchName="Sheet1";
  
  const range=e.range;
  const cell=range.getA1Notation();
  const sheet=range.getSheet();
  const name=sheet.getSheetName();
 
  if ((cell == matchCell) && (name == matchName)){
      
    Logger.log("action performed");
  
  } 

}
```